# Update label which shows the current time in every second in Swift 3

Tags: swift, timer, nstextfield

I'm trying to create a label with Swift which will be updated in every second. I have been trying for a couple of hours (I've only recently started with Swift) but I haven't been able to complete it.

I have read some documentation and looked at others' answers. So far, I have this:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: NSTextField!

  var timer = Timer()

  let date = Date()
  let calendar = Calendar.current
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimeLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
  }

  override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
  }

  func updateTimeLabel() {
    timeLabel.stringValue = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
  }

}
```

So what this does is that it updates the time label – but only once – and that's when the view loads. Although I added a `Timer` into the `viewDidLoad` function, with an interval of 1 second, the label remains static.

Could anyone point out to me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

`date` is a constant in your code. **It never changes.**

You should reinitialize the date when the update happens.

```
func updateTimeLabel() {
    timeLabel.stringValue = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
}
```

Comment: Wow, nice catch! I can't believe I was spending so much time over such a simple error. I upvoted you, but it won't show until I have 15 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

in your case the `updateTimeLabel` is being called after every second but the `date` immutable variable is not being updated because it is once set with the current date. Also if you want to update `date` constant you need to use `var` instead of `let`.

to get the updated date time everytime your updateTileLabel is called you need to do the following

```
func updateTimeLabel() {
    timeLabel.stringValue = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
}
```